# Sending HTML formatted emails using script from CentOS not working in MS Outlook

Tags: html, linux, outlook, centos, mailx

I am trying to send formatted HTML emails from my linux CentOS server (Amazon EC2) using a script. I am sending it to a gmail account and a work email account and we use Outlook 2016.

the email gets formatted in gmail ok but in outlook it prints out the full html tags too.

**myScript**

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
EMAILS="myGmailAddressa@gmail.com, myWorkEmail@company.com"

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">" > /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<html" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<head>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "</head>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<body style=\"background-color:#99ccff;\" \"width:600px;\">" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<table>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<tr style=\"height:30px;\">" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<td><strong>Current Disk Size:</strong></td>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "<td>$CURRENT</td>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "</tr>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "</table>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "</body>" >> /tmp/testemail.html
echo "</html>" >> /tmp/testemail.html

(cat /tmp/testemail.html) | mail -s "$(echo -e "Test 7 MIME- HTML Formatted OUTPUT \nMIME-Version: 1.0 \nContent-Type: text/html")" $EMAILS EOF
```

Here is the content of `testemail.html` file after I run the script.

**testemail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#99ccff;" "width:600px;">
<table>
<tr style="height:30px;">
<td><strong>Current Disk Size:</strong></td>
<td>85</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Gmail**

[image]

**Outlook**

[image]

**NOTE:**

> I know I can just forward the emails from gmail to my work email but
>   that is **NOT** what I want to do. I know this will help others so I want it to be done correct.

Has anyone ever had this problem before and/or  have a solution  to how this can be fixed.

G

Answer (score 0):

your script violates lot of mail rfc, so expected result is the body of your message is broken. there's no time to explain, just try to use mutt to build correct messsage body:

```
cat /tmp/testemail.html | mutt \
 -e "set content_type=text/html" \
 -e "set from=your@address.com" \
 -e "set realname=daemon" \
 -e "set send_charset=utf-8" \
 -s "test subject" \
 myGmailAddressa@gmail.com \
 myWorkEmail@company.com
```

and don't forget install it before usage: `yum install -y mutt`.

Comment: I am new to linux scripting so if you say I am violating mail rfc and then say no time to explain how am I or others reading this suppose to get it right if I don't know what is correct and you haven't got time to tell or show me were I am going wrong?

Comment: I did try that and now it doesn't send to my work email only sends to gmail.

Comment: unix way is use a tool, which make right for you, like a mutt. mail rfc is a lot of reading, I guess you wan't it all: rfc 1123, 1138, 1148, 1327, 1556, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2049, 2156, 2184, 2231, 2646, 3798, 4288, 4289, 4855, 5147, 5335.

Comment: I fixed command line in answer, it should sent mail to both addresses.